# What does x() and x[:] mean in MATLAB and what are the Python equivalent

Tags: python, matlab, syntax

I'm reading my assignment's MATLAB source code and it says:

```
N = 100; % Number of training points
x = sort(10*rand(N,1)-5);
t = 5*x.^3 - x.^2 + x;
noise_var = 300;
t = t + randn(size(x)).*sqrt(noise_var);

% Chop out some x data
pos = find(x>0 & x<2);
x(pos) = [];
t(pos) = [];

testx = [-5:0.1:5]';
```

and

```
orders = [1:8];
for i = 1:length(orders)
```

I'm guessing this part:
x(pos) = [];
t(pos) = [];
talks about creating an array with size of pos while this part

```
orders = [1:8];
for i = 1:length(orders)
```

Talks about an array that contains a number from 1 to 8, and I'm not sure why there is a loop statement without any action taken. Also, maybe can you explain the python equivalent as I have to translate it to python

Answer (score 1):

`x(pos)` is used to get the element at the `pos` index in the vectorised `x`. Check [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html) documentation for array indexing in MATLAB. So in your code example you are setting the value for x(pos), t(pos) as empty array.

`[start:end]` returns the 1D array starting with `start` and `end` as the last element and with a default step size of '1'.

eg.
`[1:4]` returns the array `[1 2 3 4]`

Comment: “[start:end] returns the 1D array...” The brackets are superfluous, and might actually show things down. Square brackets are for concatenation, but here they concatenate only one array, so don’t do anything.